# How to filter a Array of objects but change order

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Lets say I have an array of objects[] and an array of numbers.

```
let objects = [
{name: apple, id:1},
{name: banana, id:2},
{name: orange, id:5}
];

let numbers = [5, 1];
```

I want to filter the object array, so only the id that matches with the numbers stays, and the order should be changed to match the numbers array.

```
result should be [{name: orange, id:5} , {name: apple, id:1} ]
```

Can I do it with javascript object prototypes? or can I use 3rd party tools like lodash ?

I've tried with code bellow, but it keeps the order of the original list:

```
result = object.filter(p => {
    return numbers.includes(parseInt(p.id));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the wanted items by finding the objects.

```js
var objects = [{ name: 'apple', id: 1 }, { name: 'banana', id: 2 }, { name: 'orange', id: 5 }],
    numbers = [5, 1],
    result = numbers.map(id => objects.find(o => o.id === id));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A canonical solution for finding and reordering could be to use a hash table or [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with a fas access of O(1) and map the wanted parts.

For examle here a solution with an abstraction of the key byhanding over the original data array, an array of wanted values and the key.

```js
const
    getObjects = (data, values, key) => values.map(
        Map.prototype.get,
        objects.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o[key], o), new Map)
    ),
    objects = [{ name: 'apple', id: 1 }, { name: 'banana', id: 2 }, { name: 'orange', id: 5 }],
    values = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange'],
    result = getObjects(objects, values, 'name');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: that is good one. Though how do we filter it without id.. lets say., I dont have ID., but need to reorder by name.. e.g. I need reordering by [banana, apple, orange]

Comment: @shabarinath, please see edit. if you want all objects in different order, you could sort the array by taking the index of the wanted order.

Answer (score 2):

Just `Array.map` and `Array.find`. You don't need to `Array.filter`.

```js
const items = [{name: 'apple', id:1}, {name: 'banana', id:2}, {name: 'orange', id:5}]

const numbers = [5, 1]

const result = numbers.map(n => items.find(i => i.id === n))

console.log(result)
```

Since you're mapping over `numbers`, the order of the `result` Array is identical to `numbers`.

Answer (score 2):

It keeps the order because you iterate over objects. If you want to use the order from numbers you have to iterate over numbers.

You didn't say if the ids in numbers had to exist in objects, my solution works even if a stray id finds its way into numbers

```
let result = []
numbers.forEach(
        element => { if (objects.find(anObject => anObject.id == element))
                         result.push(objects.find(anObject => anObject.id == element)) })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
checkObject(obj, arr) {
 let x;
 for (x in arr) {
    if(arr[x].id == obj.id){
      return true;
     }
 }
 return false;
}

let items = [{name: 'apple', id:1}, {name: 'banana', id:2}, {name: 'orange', id:5}]
let numbers = [5, 1];
checkObject(items, numbers);
```

you can try this function to check if your numbers array matches in your array of Object.